# "a past that we have forgotten about" and "a lot of pasts"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Consider these three sentences:

**A**:  Everybody has a past and everybody has a future.

**B**:   And the fallacy comes from idealizing a past that we have forgotten about.
(from Google)

**C**:   The present moment is made of a lot of pasts. (from Google)

I think "a past" in A is a personal past experience, and it's rightly used.

But how about "a past that we have forgotten about" in B and "a lot of pasts" in C?

I've heard such words as "a past that should never have existed" and "a past that has never been present".

Can you really use "a past" meaning a past time related to the whole universe, not an individual person?

Comment: Hello, m-d. The first place to check is in a decent dictionary; we are fortunate to have several a mouse-click or two away. If the definitions provided by say three (AHD? CED? Collins? M-W ...?) that you check in don't sanction the usage, then tell us and I'm sure someone will give an answer. // The use of the indefinite article with 'past' is of course quite legitimate in certain contexts.

Comment: Your third example might be alluding to [Feynman's sum-over-histories](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/feynmans-sum-over-histories.181620/) (quantum theory). Whatever - all the cited usages look fine to me.

Comment: Thank you Edwin Ashworth and FumbleFingers.

  Now I understand all the usages are OK.
 By the way can I say "the past", which we often see and hear, is the generalization of pasts, just as "the lion" means lions in general and "the summer" means summers in general?

Comment: *“And all our **yesterdays** have lighted fools / 
The way to dusty death. Out, out, brief candle!”*

Comment: << [C]an I say "the past" ... is the generalization of pasts, just as "the lion" means lions in general and "the summer" means summers in general? >> {Lions (in general) (over the Earth's history and future)} is arguably well-defined, though we all tend to over-generalise / over-specify ("Lions will eat you" / lions eat zebra [not in most zoos]). 'The past' usually has some restricting context (in the past, soldiers would study ... take a written test). 'The summer' seems quite general, but surrounding text will usually add constraints: the Arctic summer is quite unlike that in Death Valley.

Comment: Thank you Edwin Ashworth. Again I ask you. Do you think "the past" is definitely a generalization of "pasts"?

Comment: **The** past = The past in general; the past taken as a whole; the past that we are all aware off. **A/an** [noun] = One example of a/an [noun].

Comment: If the final quote is about interpretations of quantum theory, then language is going to be used in a specialised, and ad hoc way: it's not as though the entire English-speaking population has been talking about quantum theoretical interpretations for hundreds of years. Any vocabulary will have to be specially selected and either explicitly explained or deducible from context, and it appears to be deducible from context. When asking whether it can be used, do you expect the language police to turn up at Feynman's door? Are you asking if it's comprehensible? If there's a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a case of "a past story" with "story" being implied. This is a common figure of the speech.

B: And the fallacy comes from idealizing a past (story) that we have forgotten about.

C: The present moment is made of a lot of (past stories)